# How to iterate MySQL fetchall() results into tinter listbox and center results

Tags: python, mysql, loops, tkinter, listbox

just to explain whats going here: I have a search function that runs a MySQL query using user input `[givenLocation]`. It is supposed to dump the contents of the query into the listbox `[self.lookuplist]`. My issue is that currently it will only dump the first result even though I am using the fetchall() function. I am a self-taught python developer but I have not been able to find any information on this from other sources. Here is my code:

```
def searchL_button(self):

    i = 0

    givenLocation = self.top3.searchEntry1.get()
    searchLookup = ("SELECT Status, Serial, Product_Code, Location FROM Registers WHERE Location = %s")
    cursor9.execute(searchLookup, [givenLocation])
    locRes = cursor9.fetchall() [i]

    for i in locRes:
        self.lookupList.insert(END, locRes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the variable `locRes` to only contain the first result of your query. Change the last few lines to the following

```
locRes = cursor9.fetchall()

for curRes in locRes:
    self.lookupList.insert(END, curRes)
```

Comment: Thank you for all of your help!